# Automatically save draft email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for VBA code for Outlook 2013 that will automatically save a draft either when opening the composition window, when replying or forwarding an email (it's OK if it fires on newly-composed messages also) or just before sending it when hitting the Send button.

Essentially emulating hitting the "Save" icon or Ctrl-S either before composing or before the message gets sent.

Outlook generates a "Could not complete the operation because the mail provider does not support it" error when replying to or forwarding a non-Google Apps account email when Google Apps accounts are combined with other email accounts in Outlook.

I discovered that a work-around is to manually save the email before sending it. I can do that manually but often forget. Can't do it after the error message appears. Trying to save after the "could not complete" error is thrown results in another error.

BTW, I already have a routine running off the Application_ItemSend event; will adding another conflict?

Update: Here is a version of what I tried:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
' Runs when the item is being sent.
    Call AutoSaveDraft(item)
    Call CheckSubject(item)
End Sub
```

(CheckSubject fires)

```
Private Sub AutoSaveDraft(item As Object)
    item.Save
    SendKeys "+{F12}" ' Save the message. ##
    SendKeys "^S"
    Sleep 1000 ' Pause execution 1 second. The Windows sleep function is      called in the beginning ##
End Sub
```

(Yes, I have all three potential save methods. Have also tried them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to call the *Save* method in the ItemSend event handler if it helps to avoid issues.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I'm so late getting back to check on an answer. I though that would be the case, but I have tried it three different ways without success. (which probably means I'm doing something wrong).  I have tried using item.save within Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean), a save subroutine using item.save and sendkeys methods called by Item_Send, all without any efect (the other routine called by Item_send, to check for absence of s subject line, seems to work just fine)

Comment: I'd suggest updating the original post instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original poster doesn't make it clear, this is what actually works to prevent the errors related to non-Google Apps accounts when simply hitting **Send**:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
     Item.Save
End Sub
```